# containerd - image might be filtered out message

Tags: containerd

I have 2 machines one is connected to the internet and the other one is not. Whenever I need to get any container image in the offline machine, in the online machine I am pulling the image by docker then save it as a tar then I take this tar file and import it in the offline machine.

The online machine has docker engine but the offline machine has Containerd. Last time when I pulled [this image](https://quay.io/repository/containerdisks/ubuntu) and tried to import it, I am getting "image might be filtered out" error message.

```
ctr images import quay.ubuntu.22.04.tar
ctr: image might be filtered out
```

I didn't find much details on this error message but as per [this thread](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/2772) the issue maybe due to mismatch between the architecture used for the image and the one for the machine, but I am not able to know the architecture used for the image .. how can I check that !

If anyone faced the same issue before and has any idea how to get rid of it, it would be really helpful.

I am using containerd-1.6.8-linux-amd64.

I downgraded the containerd I am using from v1.6.8 to v1.6.6 and I faced the same problem but when I downgraded to v1.5.13 the image imported but still I am getting below message.

```
 ctr images import /vms/quay.ubuntu.22.04.tar
unpacking quay.io/containerdisks/ubuntu:22.04 (sha256:be5e9b2b413ee416c125b39d3b28f719d1c484c0384475ab890122150be67061)...ctr: content digest sha256:f00d98d62674e83365d5b09b4007a7e346f9dc993f7e67976f63cec65ca22325: not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind did not use `--all-platforms` flag by default. That was changed by below PR. Running `brew upgrade kind` fixed it for me

```
kind --version
kind version 0.17.0
```

See kind issue [#2957](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/pull/2957) and [other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73962956/unable-to-load-local-docker-image-in-kind-kubernetes-cluster).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in pulling the image with docker, save it as a tar, then importing it  with ctr in docker. simply, Pulling it with docker or so, ended with an error.

I solve it by using 'ctr/containerd' in the whole process pulling, saving and importing the image.