# Unable to load local docker image in kind kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, arm, apple-silicon, kind

I have an Apple Macbook Pro with an M1 chip, where I have a local kubernetes cluster running through `Kind`. The thing is I don't understand how `Kind` deals with docker images from different platforms/architectures. The thing is I have an application installed via `Helm` that points to some docker images with `linux/amd64` architecture, and when I install it through `helm` (`helm install -n [namespace] [repo] [app]`), it works like a charm (I can actually look at the downloaded images and see that their architecture is `amd64`). However, when I download the same image to my local docker registry with `docker pull [my-image]`, and then try to load it to the `kind` cluster with `kind load docker-image [my-image] [my-cluster]`, it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Image: "[my-image]" with ID "sha256:d3a8..." not yet present on node "[my-cluster]-control-plane", loading...
ERROR: failed to load image: command "docker exec --privileged -i [my-cluster]-control-plane ctr --namespace=k8s.io images import --digests --snapshotter=overlayfs -" failed with error: exit status 1
Command Output: ctr: image might be filtered out
```

And after googling the error a little bit, I could see that it is due to the mismatch of architectures between the image and the `kind` cluster.

Could someone explain to me the reason for these different behaviors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After asking in the [Kind Slack channel in the Kubernetes workspace](https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/CEKK1KTN2) I could finally find the answer to my question: [whole thread here](https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/CEKK1KTN2/p1665033551816149).

TL,DR; `Kind` was unable to load the images with architectures that don't match the host architecture because it lacked a required `--all-platforms` argument in the call to the `ctr` tool used by `kind load docker-image` to load the docker images into the cluster. A [PR to fix the issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/pull/2957) was filed and it will be fixed in future releases of `Kind`.

Answer (score 2):

**This can also happen when you have to run kind as a super user**

Ensure to:

- Check that the said image exists (`docker images`)
- Run the command as `sudo` if required
- Include image tag as part of the image
- `sudo kind load docker-image test-img:1.0 --name test-cluster`